# Development of a For-Loop Code to Instantiate only 3 Array Objects at a time

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, unity-game-engine, slideshow

So I've got a little code to create a dynamic gallery that creates a master array of file locations, a loader coroutine that loads the image into a texture and a function to instantiates a prefab that takes the texture, adds it as a sprite and then parents the prefab accordingly. Finally a for-loop then repeats this process until I've run through the entire array of files and populates my gallery with all of the images. This works for a small gallery, but as my gallery grows it can get unwieldy and start grabbing massive amounts of memory. My question is how can I go about modifying this code to only load 3 images at a time (left-center-right)? I've got all my images in a scroll container and I'd like to be able to know when the images slides off-screen as a signal to load the next (or previous). Has anyone done this before that wouldn't mind sharing a little code?

```
public Texture2D tex;
public string[] galleryImages;

GameObject galleryThumbHolder;
string[] arctopithecusImages;
string[] arctopithecusPNGImages;
string[] gulonImages;
string[] scythianWolfImages;
string[] simivulpaImages;
string[] succorathImages;
string[] tatusImages;

int currentIndex = 0;

// Create a master Array of all image files located in all Image locations
void Start()
{
    // Build Gallery Arrays
    arctopithecusImages = Directory.GetFiles(@"/Users/kenmarold/Screenshots/ARCTOPITHECUS/", "*.jpg");
    arctopithecusPNGImages = Directory.GetFiles(@"/Users/kenmarold/Screenshots/ARCTOPITHECUS/", "*.png");
    gulonImages = Directory.GetFiles(@"/Users/kenmarold/Screenshots/GULON/", "*.jpg");
    scythianWolfImages = Directory.GetFiles(@"/Users/kenmarold/Screenshots/SCYTHIAN-WOLF/", "*.png");
    simivulpaImages = Directory.GetFiles(@"/Users/kenmarold/Screenshots/SIMIVULPA/", "*.png");
    succorathImages = Directory.GetFiles(@"/Users/kenmarold/Screenshots/SUCCORATH/", "*.png");
    tatusImages = Directory.GetFiles(@"/Users/kenmarold/Screenshots/TATUS/", "*.png");
    // Concatenate all Folder Array into single Array
    galleryImages = 
        arctopithecusImages.Concat(arctopithecusPNGImages)
            .Concat(gulonImages)
            .Concat(scythianWolfImages)
            .Concat(simivulpaImages)
            .Concat(succorathImages)
            .Concat(tatusImages)
            .ToArray();

    for(int i = 0; i < galleryImages.Length; i++)
    {
        StartCoroutine("loader", currentIndex);
        currentIndex++;
    }
}

IEnumerator loader(int indexNum)
{
    WWW www = new WWW("file://" + galleryImages[indexNum]);         // get the first file from disk

    yield return www;                                               // Wait unill its loaded
    tex = new Texture2D(512,512);                                   // create a new Texture2D
    www.LoadImageIntoTexture(tex);                                  // put the image file into the new Texture2D

    createGalleryImages(tex);
}

public void createGalleryImages(Texture2D tex)
{
    // Instantiate Gallery Thumb Prefab and Load in Sprite
    //GameObject galleryThumb = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Prefabs/GalleryImageHolder")) as GameObject;
    GameObject galleryThumb = Instantiate(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GalleryImgHolder")) as GameObject;
    Image galleryImg = galleryThumb.GetComponent<Image>();

    Rect rct = new Rect(0, 0, tex.width, tex.height);               // Define Rect arg
    Vector2 pvt = new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f);                          // Define Pivot arg
    galleryImg.sprite = Sprite.Create(tex, rct, pvt);

    // Set Gallery Thumb Parent
    galleryThumb.transform.SetParent(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GalleryThumbs").transform);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar once, the way I implemented it, was with a trigger, that detects the entering object and get the index assigned to that object, in this case could be the index of your images in the array, this way you can know which is the current image that you are showing in the center, and can load another image if the user scrolls left or right.
Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks, that helps me visualize things a lot better.